mssql, SqlAlchemy, and "ForeignKeyConstraint with duplicate source column references are not supported."
I am coming across a little feature-ette of SqlAlchemy:
ForeignKeyConstraint with duplicate source column references are not supported.
when attempting in Python:
pd.read_sql_table('my_table', con=engine)
The table does indeed have duplicate source column references, but this is totally valid:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_table] (
    [id]                                   INT             IDENTITY (10, 10) NOT NULL,
...
    [manufacturer_ref]                     VARCHAR (32)    NULL,
    [cpu_manufacturer_ref]                 VARCHAR (32)    NULL,
    [vendor_ref]                           VARCHAR (32)    NULL,
...
    CONSTRAINT [PK_my_table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_my_table_cpu_manufacturer] FOREIGN KEY ([cpu_manufacturer_ref]) REFERENCES [dbo].[company] ([id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_my_table_manufacturer] FOREIGN KEY ([manufacturer_ref]) REFERENCES [dbo].[company] ([id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_my_table_vendor] FOREIGN KEY ([vendor_ref]) REFERENCES [dbo].[company] ([id])
);

Apparently, this was a bug in 2017/2018 in whatever version of SqlAlchemy was around then so I would not think it would be a bug today.
I have tried stipulating column names in the call so not associate the FK references, but this does not change anything. Is there a workaround of sorts?
UPDATE:
So, I initially thought the error was occurring because we have three columns referencing the same secondary table. As an experiment, I removed the lesser-used FKs and replaced them with indexes. I am still getting the same error.

What driver are you using (or what is the output of engine.url)?

ODBC+Driver+18+for+SQL+Server
